# How to ensure JOptionPane opens on a specific monitor?

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane

Working with a Java App that kicks off a number of background processes.

If there is an issue the `JOptionPane` pops up with some general information.

The workstation has more than one monitor and the `JOptionPane` could appear 
on any of them.

There are no associated windows to use as the "parent" for the `JOptionPane`.

Is there a way to specify on which monitor the `JOptionPane` should appear?

Answer (score 2):

You can specify where the dialog will appear if you use `JOptionPane` directly, by instantiating it. Example:

```
JOptionPane pane = new JOptionPane("Hi!");
JDialog dialog = pane.createDialog("Look at me");
dialog.setVisible(true);
```

In the example, before you call `dialog.setVisible()` you can position the dialog, e.g.:

```
dialog.setBounds(100, 100, 100, 100);
```

To show the dialog on a display that is not your default, you have to get the bounds ([`Rectangle`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Rectangle.html)) of the desired display, and you can position your dialog to be inside that area.

Here is how you can get the list of your displays (and their bounds). Code taken from the Javadoc of [`GraphicsConfiguration`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/GraphicsConfiguration.html)):

```
Rectangle virtualBounds = new Rectangle();
GraphicsEnvironment ge = GraphicsEnvironment.
        getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
GraphicsDevice[] gs =
        ge.getScreenDevices();
for (int j = 0; j < gs.length; j++) {
    GraphicsDevice gd = gs[j];
    GraphicsConfiguration[] gc =
        gd.getConfigurations();
    for (int i=0; i < gc.length; i++) {
        virtualBounds =
            virtualBounds.union(gc[i].getBounds());
    }
}
```

Comment: seems like as still bug (parent isn't on 2nd display, without a parent)

Comment: If you have 4 monitors all of the same size, won't this produce essentially 4 elements in the array with the same bounds or are all 4 windows calculated as one large window with 4 segments and each segment a subset of the overall size?

Comment: @user3601445 The bounds of a display is not (0;0) based, they are absolute and do not overlap. So for example your default display should have (x=0, y=0) and if you have a 2nd display on the left, it should have a negative x like x=-1024. But why don't you just try it out? Run the code and print the `virtualBounds` rectangles.